# What is the longest route to hatch eggs?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm asking because to hatch eggs, it takes a certain amount of steps to hatch them. In Gen V, I would always use SkyArrow Bridge because it was simply too easy to hold up in one direction, then down in another direction.

What's the longest possible route either horizontally or vertically in one direction (just holding one direction button) in all of Pokemon X & Y?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Lumiose City Centrico Plaza**

This plaza surrounds the Lumiose City Gym in a circle. If you hold left or right on that screen you can go forever.

Answer (score 14):

Route 7, which is the path right in front of the Daycare is very long at 220 steps, straight and has no obstacles or long grass.

The Daycare is roughly in the middle, and the path from it to either end and back is long enough for eggs to have a chance of spawning (which requires at least 255 steps).

Combined with the easy access to the Daycare to get new eggs, this may be the best place to hatch an egg in Pokémon X and Y.

With a Flame Body Pokémon combined with the Hatching O-power you should be hatching in no time.

Comment: And the Battle Chateau and Berry Farm are both right there as well. So you have something to do while you wait for eggs to show up.

Comment: And you can easily bike through the connecting cave to cyllage for the massage, great for raising pokemon happiness through steps.

Answer (score 1):

Where the electric gym is, put a quarter to hold the joystick in one direction so it will move your avatar around the circle forever.

Comment: The comment about the quarter is actually valuable and hasn't been addressed in any of the other answers.